# UIButton height not being set correctly on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I have an `UITableView` which holds a list of items. For each `UITableViewcell` in that table, depending on a property from the associated object to that cell, I toggle the visibility of an `UIButton` by changing the height constraint constant to 0, or to a value defined to make it visible. I've checked the `Clip to Bounds` option on the Xcode designer for that button.

If I feed the table view a list of items that set some of the buttons visible, and others *hidden* and scroll, the cells that had the button visible may have it *hidden*, and vice-versa. This is more noticeable when there's few cells with the button, and the rest without it.

The method that contains the logic to *show* or *hide* the `UIButton` is from within the `UITableViewCell` custom class for the cells, as it follows:

```
public partial class UITableViewCellCustom : UITableViewCell
{
    public Object obj;

    public void SetObject(Object obj)
    {
        // Do something with obj...

        // Do something with the obj that determines if the buttons should be collapsed or not
        Boolean collapseButton = ...;

        ToggleButtonVisibility(collapseButton);
    }

    private void ToggleButtonVisibility(Boolean collapse) 
    {
        NSLayoutConstraint uiButtonCancelHeightConstraint = UIButtonCancel.Constraints
            .FirstOrDefault(query => query.FirstItem == UIButtonCancel
                                  && query.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height);
                                  
        NSLayoutConstraint uiButtonCancelTopConstraint = this.ContentView.Constraints
            .FirstOrDefault(query => query.FirstItem == UIButtonCancel
                                  && query.FirstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Top);

        if (collapse)
        {
            uiButtonCancelHeightConstraint.Constant = 0;
            uiButtonCancelTopConstraint.Constant = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            uiButtonCancelHeightConstraint.Constant = 30;
            uiButtonCancelTopConstraint.Constant = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

The `SetObject` method is called from the `UITableViewSource` class that gets the object from the correct index and sets it to the cell ( No problem here ). Then, while some `UILabel`s texts are changed with the values from the object, I check if the button is required or not ( No problem here ). When I call the `ToggleButtonVisibility` method, and attempt to change the two constraints -- **height** and **top** -- the values are applied, the **top** constraint is visibly changed, but the **height** constraint seems to be ignored when the cell is reused.

I've tried to force the `ClipToBounds` to `true`, force the method in the main thread, but none of them worked. What am I missing here?

---

**Forgot to mention:** When the button is pressed, the table view is cleared ( I feed the source an empty list, and reload the data ), an long task is performed, and then a new list is applied to the table, but the cell in question remains with the button *bugged*.

---

### Notes:

- Hiding the button by changing the `Alpha` to `0` or by set the `Hidden` to `true` is not an option, since it will leave an *hole* within the tableview.

Comment: Do you need to change the constraints to toggle visibility? Can't you just change Alpha or Hidden flag of the button?

Comment: I agree with @lowleetak why don't you  set `alpha = 0` or `hidden = true` to hide the button?

Comment: @lowleetak Unfortunately, if I toggle the visibility by changing the Alpha / Hidden flag, the list will contain _holes_ in it, so it's not an option.

Comment: Also, you have tried to update the data for UITableView and call tableView.ReloadData or tableView.RemoveRow? Modifying the constraint will still leave the cell in the TableView and you might have TableView separator still showing.

Comment: I've tried to feed an empty array to the table view, reloading the data, and then feed the "live" data and reloading again to ensure all the data and rows are updated. It's still happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this problem by wrapping the `UIButton` on a `UIView` and then resizing the view depending on my needs.

Comment: I have the same problem and the solution is so sad :(